Non-semisimple Lie groups and Higgs bundles
$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface. Let $G$ be a real reductive Lie group, $H$ be a maximal compact subgroup of $G$ and $H^{\mathbb C}$ be its complexification. Let $$H^{\mathbb C} \rightarrow \GL(\mathfrak{m}^{\mathbb C})$$ be the complexified isotropy representation, defined in terms of the Cartan decomposition $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{h}+\mathfrak{m}$ of the Lie algebra of G and using the fact that $[\mathfrak{h}, \mathfrak{m}] \subset \mathfrak{m}$.
Now we  define Higgs bundle as  follows: A $G$-Higgs bundle is a pair $(E, \phi)$ where $E$ is a principal $H^{\mathbb C}$-bundle over $X$ and $\phi$ is a holomorphic section of the vector bundle $E(\mathfrak{m}^{\mathbb C}) \otimes K$ where $K$ is the canonical line bundle over $X$. The section $\phi$ is called the Higgs field. Two G-Higgs bundles $(E, \phi)$ and $(E^\prime, \phi^\prime)$  are isomorphic if there is an isomorphism $E  \cong E^\prime$  which takes $\phi \cong \phi^\prime$ under the induced isomorphism $E(\mathfrak{m}^{\mathbb C}) \cong E^\prime(\mathfrak{m}^{\mathbb C})$.  Examples are $\SL(2, \mathbb R)$- Higgs bundles, $SL(2, \mathbb C)$-Higgs bundles, $\SO_0(p,q)$-Higgs bundles etc.
Is there any notion of a $G$-Higgs bundle for $G$ a non-semisimple Lie group? Explicitly, is there any notion of Higgs bundles for $G = \SO_0(2,1) \ltimes \mathbb R^3$ or $G = \SO(3) \ltimes \mathbb R^3$?

Don't you mean to ask for a notion of a $G$-Higgs bundle for $G$ non-reductive instead of non-semisimple, since this was your initial hypothesis on $G$? There are (real) reductive Lie groups that are not semisimple (e.g. $G=GL(n,\mathbb{R})$) and your definition applies equally well to them.

@PedroLauridsenRibeiro Can we define $SO_0(2,1) \ltimes \mathbb R^3$-Higgs bundle?

As far as I know, the (three-dimensional in the OP) Poincaré and Euclidean groups are not reductive, so I have no idea. That's also why I insist that you're actually asking for a notion of $G$-Higgs bundles for $G$ non-reductive - the case of $G$ reductive but not semisimple is already covered by the definition presented in the OP and the examples you're interested in are (I think) non-reductive. You should amend the title and body of your question in order to address that, they are slightly misleading as they stand.

One can replace $\mathfrak m$ by $\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h$ where $\mathfrak g$ is the Lie algebra of $G$ and $\mathfrak h$ is the Lie algebra of $H$. We clearly have $[\mathfrak h,\mathfrak h ] \subseteq \mathfrak h$ so the action of $\mathfrak h$ on $\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h$ is well-defined, and in the case where $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak h+\mathfrak m$ this will certainly agree with $\mathfrak m$. After this replacement everything else can be done in the same way.
I don't know if this notion is useful.

My guess is that some issues will arise when one considers moduli spaces of Higgs bundles (and their relation to character schemes) if the group is non-reductive. But maybe OP does not care about these.

The examples the OP is interested in are a very special kind of non-reductive Lie group - to wit, the semidirect product of a semisimple Lie group with a non-compact Abelian Lie group. Can such issues be circumvented in this case?

There is a (related but not quite the same) construction which is valid for any Lie group $G$ and any closed (hence Lie) subgroup $H\subset G$ over any smooth base manifold $X$ which may be helpful.
One starts with a principal $G$-bundle $\pi:P\rightarrow X$ over $X$. Consider the $G$-bundle $\pi_H:P/H\rightarrow X$ associated to $\pi$, whose total space $P/H$ is the quotient of $P$ modulo the right action of $H$ on $P$, whose bundle projection $\pi_H$ factors $\pi$ through the natural quotient map $\rho_H:P\rightarrow P/H$ (i.e. $\pi=\pi_H\circ\rho_H$) and whose typical fiber is the homogeneous space $G/H$. One can see $\rho_H$ as a principal $H$-bundle projection onto $P/H$ (see e.g. Proposition 5.5, pp. 57 of the book by S. Kobayashi and K. Nomizu, Foundations of Differential Geometry, Volume I, Wiley, 1963 for more details). A classical result in principal $G$-bundle theory (see e.g. Proposition 5.6, pp. 57-58 of ibid.) then states that the structure group reductions $\sigma:Q\subset P\rightarrow X$ of $\pi$ to principal $H$-bundles over $X$ are in a one-to-one correspondence with smooth sections $\phi$ of $\pi_H$ - more precisely, one can recover $\phi$ from $\sigma$ by the formula $\phi(p)=\sigma^{-1}(p)$ for each $p\in X$ since then $$\phi(\sigma(q))=\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(q))=qH=\rho_H(q)$$ and therefore $$\pi_H(\phi(\sigma(q)))=\sigma(q)$$ for all $q\in Q$. The first formula also shows that $(p,q)\in X\times P$ satisfies $\phi(p)=\rho_H(q)=qH$ (that is, $(p,q)$ belongs to the total space $\phi^*P$ of the pullback bundle $\phi^*\rho_H=pr_1|_{\phi^*P}$, where $pr_j$, $j=1,2$ are the canonical projections of a cartesian product of two sets onto the first and second components respectively) if and only if $q\in Q$ and $\sigma(q)=p$, so one is also able to recover $Q$ and $\sigma$ from $\phi$ by noticing that $Q=pr_2(\phi^*P)$ and recalling that $\sigma=\pi|_Q$. One particularly has that $\sigma$ is canonically identified with $\phi^*\rho_H$. Such a $\phi$ is also called a Higgs field. One may as well call the pair $(\sigma,\phi)$ a Higgs bundle over $X$.
The origin and reason for the terminology are rather obvious. The choice of Higgs field $\phi$ tells us how the group $G$ of "gauge" (i.e. internal = fiberwise) symmetries of $\pi$ breaks down to a smaller subgroup $H$ through structure group reduction from $\pi$ to $\sigma$. This also translates to the reduction of principal $G$-connections on $\pi$ to principal $H$-connections on $\sigma$ - such a reduction is possible precisely when $\phi$ is parallel w.r.t. the corresponding induced $G$-connection on $\pi_H$ (see e.g. Proposition 7.4, pp. 88-89 of ibid.). By the way, this is actually the notion of Higgs field used in particle physics.
To get from here to a setting closer to that of the OP in the spirit of Will Sawin's answer, one observes that the tangent bundle of $P/H$ is (identified with) the associated vector $H$-bundle $P\times_H(\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h})$ over $P/H$, recalling that the $H$-action on the quotient vector space $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$ is the one induced from $Ad_G|_H$ by the quotient map. Under such an identification, the differential $d\phi$ of the Higgs field $\phi$ becomes a $Q\times_H(\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h})$-valued 1-form on $X$. The latter vector bundle over $X$ can be identified with $TQ$, so the criterion for reducibility of a principal $G$-connection on $\pi$ to a principal $H$-connection on $\sigma$ translates to the requirement that $d\phi$ takes only horizontal values with respect to the given principal $G$-connection.
What happens if $G$ is real reductive and $H$ is a maximal compact subgroup? One can then exploit the (henceforth called) polar diffeomorphism $(h,X)\mapsto h\exp(X)$ from $H\times\mathfrak{m}$ onto $G$ coming from the Cartan decomposition $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}\oplus\mathfrak{m}$ and identify $\mathfrak{m}$ with $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}=T_H G/H$ (recalling that $H=eH$ is the identity coset in $G/H$), which is endowed with the isotropy representation $Ad_G|_H$ (recalling on its turn that $Ad_G(h)\mathfrak{m}\subset\mathfrak{m}$ for all $h\in H$). This representation of $H$ can also be seen as the differential at $H(=eH)$ of the left action of $H$ on $G/H$ and we use it to obtain the vector $H$-bundle $\tau:E(\mathfrak{m})=Q\times_H\mathfrak{m}\rightarrow X$ associated to $\sigma$, which is then identified with the associated vector $H$-bundle $Q\times_H(\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h})$ over $M$ mentioned in the end of the the previous paragraph. As such, under the above identifications the differential $d\phi$ of the Higgs field $\phi$ can be seen as an $E(\mathfrak{m})$-valued 1-form on $X$.
The above discussion indicates that our object of interest is ultimately not $\phi$ but rather $d\phi$ if one starts with the "physical" notion of Higgs field as presented here, so perhaps one may extract from this the essential requirements for the desired answer. In the case of $X$ a Riemann surface, one can then impose additional conditions on $d\phi$ - for one, requiring $d\phi$ to be holomorphic automatically entails that $d\phi $ is a smooth section of $E(\mathfrak{m})\otimes K$ (or, more generally, $(P\times_H(\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}))\otimes K$ if $G$ is not reductive). One can as well replace $H$ and $\mathfrak{m}$ by their corresponding complexifications in the above construction.
